# ERROR in Plugin "react" was conflicted between

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, git-submodules

Im using another react repo (lets call it design), in my main react app, as a git  submodule. I use webpack to build the main app. After integrating the submodule in the app, Im getting the following error in the webpack build process -

```
ERROR in Plugin "react" was conflicted between "design/.eslintrc » @design-ui/eslint-config » ./eslint-config-react.js" and ".eslintrc » @design-ui/eslint-config » ./eslint-config-react.js".
```

Any idea whats causing this?

Comment: I had a similar problem and solved it by upgrading the react-eslint version

Comment: I tried this but didnt work.

Comment: how do you run build process? try to write your root directory in lowecase. if it didn't help try to change all directory names in path to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 eslint-config-react.js in two of these locations "design/.eslintrc » @design-ui/eslint-config » ./eslint-config-react.js" and ".eslintrc » @design-ui/eslint-config » ./eslint-config-react.js".

Remove one of these and it should work. It's conflicting because there are two.

Comment: Try to set ```resolution```  with react version in package json

Answer (score 0):

The case in your folder in bash could be wrong.

Looked into it because of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71897799/901311 and this thread: https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/4186

So if you have a folder:

```
/path/to/yourDirectory
```

Turns out these commands both work:

```
cd /path/to/yourDirectory
cd /path/to/yourdirectory
```

and `pwd` will even report whatever one you entered, but when react runs the way it reconciles absolute and relative directories breaks with this.

so doing `yarn start` from the incorrect directory will break these days.

So try to cd in using tab completion 1 directory at a time and see if your final directory is in the same case as when you were having the error.